# How to handle changing boolean field from database by ajax?

Tags: javascript, html, django, ajax

There is a piece of my html:

```
  <form action="" method="post">
  {% csrf_token %}
  {% if donate.is_taken == False %}
     <br>
      <button type="submit" class="btn" name="taken_or_not" value="not_taken">Mark as taken</button>
  {% else %}
      <button type="submit" class="btn" name="taken_or_not" value="taken">Mark as not taken</button            
  {% endif %}
  </form>
```

There is a model:

```
class Donation(models.Model):
    ...
    ...
    is_taken = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

How to create a ajax request, that the user is able to change the value 'taken_or_not' by a single button both on the page and in the database. Without any redirects, server loading etc.
I am struggling to get it.
Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

Make a route that will take the the donation id and return it's "is_taken".
Make a repeating call using ajax to the particular route.